# How to Display student attendance in gridview using SQL and Gridview

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and VS 2012 C#
I have designed database table Roll_No, Attend_Date, Attend_Status
while storing data i store like this

```
______________________________________
Roll_No Attend_Date Attend_Status
---------------------------------------
1   04-01-14    1
2   04-01-14    1
3   04-01-14    1
1   05-01-14    0
2   05-01-14    1
3   05-01-14    0
1   06-01-14    1
2   06-01-14    1
3   06-01-14    1
----------------------------------------
```

But I have to show in grid-view like this

```
__________________________________________________________________
Roll_No 04-01-14    05-01-14    06-01-14    07-01-14
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1              0              1             1
2   1              1              1             1
3   1              0              1             1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can you Help me please... 
How can I achieve this result..

Comment: Why dont u try it using DataTable. Build a datatable with desired output and bind that datatable to datagridview. Eg. dataGridView1.datasource = datatable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by listing each date as column name while doing PIVOT or use dynamic SQL to generate column list and then apply PIVOT.

[PIVOT is used to change row data to columns](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx&ei=SI7JUpO9IImHrgfHloD4BQ&usg=AFQjCNGdWJoMPLV0T2tRS40iPO2qf6P60w&sig2=jwGF7WEOPkma1ocZmDJIXA).

```
create table #attendance (rollno int,attend_date varchar(30),attend_status int)
insert into #attendance values(1,'04-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(2,'04-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(3,'04-01-14',0)
insert into #attendance values(1,'05-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(2,'05-01-14',0)
insert into #attendance values(3,'05-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(1,'06-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(2,'06-01-14',1)
insert into #attendance values(3,'06-01-14',0)

Declare @colList varchar(max)
Declare @qry varchar(max)

SET @colList = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Attend_Date) 
            FROM #attendance c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @qry = 'SELECT rollno,'+@colList+'
FROM (
    SELECT Rollno,attend_date,attend_status

    FROM #attendance
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Attend_Status)
    FOR Attend_Date IN (' + @colList + ')
) pvt '

EXEC(@qry)

drop table #attendance
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Rollno  04-01-14  05-01-14  06-01-14
1             1      1       1
2             1      0       1
3             0      1       0
```

Now you can bind this resultset to your GridView

Comment: Thanks @mhasan, I got result as I want.. Its working fine.. I had used PIVOT last year.. but that was very complex than you suggest..

Comment: @user2875907..Cheers..Happy New Year